# OpenCV Error: Bad argument in CvANN_MLP

Tags: android, opencv, neural-network

I'm using OpenCV4Android and I'm trying to make a little example of neural network to work out the arithmetic mean. So, I've decided to use **CvANN_MLP** to create the network. Everything goes well but when I train it, it fails with the next exception:

OpenCV Error: Bad argument (output training data should be a floating-point matrix with the number of rows equal to the number of training samples and the number of columns equal to the size of last (output) layer) in CvANN_MLP::prepare_to_train

I've checked the output training and its type is CV_32FC1. Also the number of rows and columns are correct. Certainly I don't know where the error is.

This is my code and I hope somebody can help me. Thanks!

```
        int train_sample_count = 10;

        float td[][] = new float[10][3];

                    //I've created this method to populate td
        populateTrainingData(td);

        Mat trainData = new Mat(train_sample_count, 2, CvType.CV_32FC1);
        Mat trainClasses = new Mat(train_sample_count, 1, CvType.CV_32FC1);
        Mat sampleWts = new Mat(train_sample_count, 1, CvType.CV_32FC1);
        Mat neuralLayers = new Mat(3, 1, CvType.CV_32SC1);

        // input layer has 2 cells
        neuralLayers.put(0, 0, 2);
        // hidden layer has 2 cells
        neuralLayers.put(1, 0, 2);
        // output layer has 2 cells
        neuralLayers.put(2, 0, 2);

        // assembles the trainData,trainClasses and weights

        for (int i = 0; i < train_sample_count; i++) {
            trainData.put(i, 0, td[i][0]);
            trainData.put(i, 1, td[i][1]);
            trainClasses.put(i, 0, td[i][2]);
            sampleWts.put(i, 0, 1);
        }

        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Assemblage is finished");

        // creates neural network with the layers of neuralLayers
        CvANN_MLP machineBrain = new CvANN_MLP(neuralLayers);

        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Neural network is created");

        // trains neural network with my data
        // parameters for neural network
        CvANN_MLP_TrainParams trainParams = new CvANN_MLP_TrainParams();
        // backward propagation
        trainParams.set_train_method(CvANN_MLP_TrainParams.BACKPROP);
        // number of iterations and sigmoidal update
        TermCriteria termC = new TermCriteria(TermCriteria.EPS
                + TermCriteria.COUNT, 10000, 1.0);
        trainParams.set_term_crit(termC);

        // optional value which is zero
        Mat simpleIndex = new Mat();
        // setting up the neural network
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Setting up is finished");
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Type of trainClasses: "
                + (trainClasses.type() == CvType.CV_32FC1));
        machineBrain.train(trainData, trainClasses, sampleWts);
```